# NoSuchFileException in LogCleaner Operation

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently we are facing NoSuchFileException in LogCleaner, which is critical error as result platform get shutown.
We are running Kafka in Kraft Mode.
The cluster is having 3 Node.
Kafka version - 3.3.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQ1U.png)

**Dump of LogSegment 4146.log.swap**

---

> Log starting offset: 4146
> baseOffset: 7435 lastOffset: 7435 count: 1 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 23 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 0 CreateTime: 1684734374514 size: 497 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 2946355956 isvalid: true
> | offset: 7435 CreateTime: 1684734374514 keySize: 55 valueSize: 372 sequence: -1 headerKeys: [] key: group_metadata::group=group-//host:8409/SmartServer payload: {"protocolType":"consumer","protocol":"range","generationId":47,"assignment":"{consumer-//host:8409/SmartServer-4fc37a78-2757-430f-b974-11ff81bf8fd9=[mdmnxst-topic-0]}"}
> baseOffset: 7740 lastOffset: 7740 count: 1 baseSequence: 0 lastSequence: 0 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 23 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 497 CreateTime: 1684919856106 size: 305 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 1149086487 isvalid: true
> | offset: 7740 CreateTime: 1684919856106 keySize: 74 valueSize: 160 sequence: 0 headerKeys: [] key: offset_commit::group=group-//host:8409/SmartServer,partition=mdmnxst-topic-0 payload: offset=24434,metadata=[Consumer clientId=consumer-//host:8409/SmartServer, groupId=group-//host:8409/SmartServer]

---

**Dump of LogSegment 6340.log**

---

> baseOffset: 7434 lastOffset: 7434 count: 1 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 23 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 333799 CreateTime: 1684734253921 size: 156 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 867707744 isvalid: true
> | offset: 7434 CreateTime: 1684734253921 keySize: 55 valueSize: 32 sequence: -1 headerKeys: [] key: group_metadata::group=group-//host:8409/SmartServer payload: {"protocolType":"consumer","protocol":null,"generationId":46,"assignment":"{}"}
> baseOffset: 7435 lastOffset: 7435 count: 1 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 partitionLeaderEpoch: 23 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 333955 CreateTime: 1684734374514 size: 497 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 2946355956 isvalid: true
> | offset: 7435 CreateTime: 1684734374514 keySize: 55 valueSize: 372 sequence: -1 headerKeys: [] key: group_metadata::group=group-//host:8409/SmartServer payload: {"protocolType":"consumer","protocol":"range","generationId":47,"assignment":"{consumer-//host:8409/SmartServer-4fc37a78-2757-430f-b974-11ff81bf8fd9=[mdmnxst-topic-0]}"}

---

*It is not normal that same baseoffset present in two log segments (4146.log.swap and 6340.log). 7435 and 7740 baseOffset should not be present 4146.log.swap when there is already 6349.log*

It happen after rebalancing and at the end it crash the platform.

How can be that possible ?

LogCleaner.log

```
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,572] INFO Cleaner 0: Beginning cleaning of log __consumer_offsets-49 (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,572] INFO Cleaner 0: Building offset map for __consumer_offsets-49... (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,593] INFO Cleaner 0: Building offset map for log __consumer_offsets-49 for 1 segments in offset range [6340, 7741). (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,612] INFO Cleaner 0: Offset map for log __consumer_offsets-49 complete. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,615] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning log __consumer_offsets-49 (cleaning prior to Wed May 24 17:17:36 SGT 2023, discarding tombstones prior to upper bound deletion horizon Wed Dec 31 07:30:00 SGT 1969)... (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,617] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning LogSegment(baseOffset=4146, size=802, lastModifiedTime=0, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1684314268109)) in log __consumer_offsets-49 into 4146 with an upper bound deletion horizon -86400000 computed from the segment last modified time of 0,retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,618] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning LogSegment(baseOffset=6340, size=427477, lastModifiedTime=1684919856000, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1684919856106)) in log __consumer_offsets-49 into 4146 with an upper bound deletion horizon -86400000 computed from the segment last modified time of 1684919856000,retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,633] INFO Cleaner 0: Swapping in cleaned segment LogSegment(baseOffset=4146, size=802, lastModifiedTime=1684919856000, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1684919856106)) for segment(s) List(LogSegment(baseOffset=4146, size=802, lastModifiedTime=0, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1684314268109)), LogSegment(baseOffset=6340, size=427477, lastModifiedTime=1684919856000, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1684919856106))) in log Log(dir=/opt/mdmadm/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.3.1/./notification/__consumer_offsets-49, topicId=tV6tksQdTLKULIHacBBvOA, topic=__consumer_offsets, partition=49, highWatermark=7742, lastStableOffset=7742, logStartOffset=4146, logEndOffset=7742) (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,643] INFO Cleaner 0: Beginning cleaning of log __consumer_offsets-49 (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,643] INFO Cleaner 0: Building offset map for __consumer_offsets-49... (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,660] INFO Cleaner 0: Building offset map for log __consumer_offsets-49 for 1 segments in offset range [6340, 7741). (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
```

Server.log

```
2023-05-24 17:47:42,860] INFO [RaftManager nodeId=1] Completed transition to FollowerState(fetchTimeoutMs=2000, epoch=58260, leaderId=2, voters=[1, 2, 3], highWatermark=Optional[LogOffsetMetadata(offset=6114862, metadata=Optional.empty)], fetchingSnapshot=Optional.empty) (org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState)
[2023-05-24 17:47:42,860] INFO [Controller 1] In the new epoch 58260, the leader is 2. (org.apache.kafka.controller.QuorumController)
[2023-05-24 17:47:49,635] ERROR Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-49 in dir /opt/mdmadm/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.3.1/./notification due to IOException (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/mdmadm/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.3.1/./notification/__consumer_offsets-49/00000000000000004146.log
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:409)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:935)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.renameTo(FileRecords.java:248)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.changeFileSuffixes(LogSegment.scala:491)
    at kafka.log.LocalLog$.$anonfun$deleteSegmentFiles$1(LocalLog.scala:989)
    at kafka.log.LocalLog$.$anonfun$deleteSegmentFiles$1$adapted(LocalLog.scala:987)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at kafka.log.LocalLog$.deleteSegmentFiles(LocalLog.scala:987)
    at kafka.log.LocalLog$.$anonfun$replaceSegments$7(LocalLog.scala:950)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79)
```

KafkaConfig

```
    advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://host1:9092
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.heartbeat.interval.ms = 2000
    broker.id = 2
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    broker.session.timeout.ms = 9000
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
    control.plane.listener.name = null
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.listener.names = CONTROLLER
    controller.quorum.append.linger.ms = 25
    controller.quorum.election.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    controller.quorum.election.timeout.ms = 1000
    controller.quorum.fetch.timeout.ms = 2000
    controller.quorum.request.timeout.ms = 2000
    controller.quorum.retry.backoff.ms = 20
    controller.quorum.voters = [1@host1-host:2181, 2@host2-host:2181, 3@host3-host:2181]
    controller.quota.window.num = 11
    controller.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delegation.token.secret.key = null
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    early.start.listeners = null
    fetch.max.bytes = 57671680
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 3000
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
    group.max.size = 2147483647
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    initial.broker.registration.timeout.ms = 60000
    inter.broker.listener.name = PLAINTEXT
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 3.3-IV3
    kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
    kafka.metrics.reporters = []
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = PLAINTEXT://host2-host:9092,CONTROLLER://host2-host:2181
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = ./notification
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 3.0-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 12
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connection.creation.rate = 2147483647
    max.connections = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1048588
    metadata.log.dir = null
    metadata.log.max.record.bytes.between.snapshots = 20971520
    metadata.log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    metadata.log.segment.min.bytes = 8388608
    metadata.log.segment.ms = 604800000
    metadata.max.idle.interval.ms = 500
    metadata.max.retention.bytes = -1
    metadata.max.retention.ms = 604800000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    node.id = 2
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 3
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    principal.builder.class = class org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.DefaultKafkaPrincipalBuilder
    process.roles = [broker, controller]
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    remote.log.index.file.cache.total.size.bytes = 1073741824
    remote.log.manager.task.interval.ms = 30000
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.backoff.max.ms = 30000
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.backoff.ms = 500
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.jitter = 0.2
    remote.log.manager.thread.pool.size = 10
    remote.log.metadata.manager.class.name = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.class.path = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.impl.prefix = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.listener.name = null
    remote.log.reader.max.pending.tasks = 100
    remote.log.reader.threads = 10
    remote.log.storage.manager.class.name = null
    remote.log.storage.manager.class.path = null
    remote.log.storage.manager.impl.prefix = null
    remote.log.storage.system.enable = false
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 30000
    replica.selector.class = null
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.server.max.receive.size = 524288
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    socket.listen.backlog.size = 50
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 2
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 3
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
```

It could be rebalancing bug in the version.